# How to connect spark with mysql using pycharm

Tags: python, mysql, jdbc, apache-spark, pycharm

i try to select a table content from mysql database to a dataframe,
i follow this steps to connect spark with mysql.

1. download `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar`
2. i put `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` at path `$SPARK_HOME/bin/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` 
   but it still not work

Code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row

sc = SparkContext()
sqlctx = SQLContext(sc)


 dataframe_mysql = sqlctx.read.format("jdbc").options(
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database",
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    dbtable="user",
    user="root",
    password="").load()
```

after that i tried to connect spark with mysql using cmd 
Start the pyspark shell with –jars argument

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark  –-jars mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
```

and also not work
i not understand why using driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
to connect to mysql
can anyone help me
 thanks in advance

i got this error

```
File "C:/Users/kcs/PycharmProjects/Flunky/SparkMySql.py", line 14, in <module>
  password="").load()
  File "C:\DataScience\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 123, in load
  return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "C:\DataScience\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-          src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "C:\DataScience\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 36, in deco
   return f(*a, **kw)
   File "C:\DataScience\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py",     line 300, in get_return_value
 py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o24.load.
 : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:114)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

[and the error on cmd is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5z3B.png)

Comment: hello rashwan can you please show the error given by the spark and to connect to the mysql u always need a driver with mysql driver never possible to connect and fetc data with it. can you once please share the error.

Answer (score 1):

Just look you download download mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar and in your code you start shell  $SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark –-jars mysql-connector-java-5.1.8-bin.jar your version of mysql driver is not same so can you once check after fix it.

Comment: that is the error must export SPARK_HIVE = true .an error occured while calling none.org.appache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

Comment: i added it in the post Sandeep

Comment: its mean its not find mysql driver can you once check on jobs ui its localhost:4040 that ur mysql jar is in classpath or not.

Answer (score 0):

When I use pyCharm Spark SQL connect MySQL, running got this error.

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="mysqltest")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")\
    .options(url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
             driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", dbtable="user", user="root", password="root")\
    .load()
df.show()
sc.stop()
```

Add mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar into %SPARK_HOME%jars, solve the bug